# Pyspark type mismatch in nested JSON structure stops schema validation

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm reading a json file with PySpark and validating the schema against a predefined data schema.

the data schema:

```
testschema = StructType([
    StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType(), True),
    StructField("a", StringType(), True),
    StructField("b", StringType(), True),
    StructField("c", StringType(), True),
    StructField("d", StringType(), True),
    StructField("e", StructType([
        StructField("e_1", IntegerType(), True)
    ]), True)
])
```

The JSON file:

```
{
    "e": {
        "e_1": "2"
    },
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c",
    "d": "d"
}
```

after reading the JSON file and validating the structure against the `testschema` definition  using the following code:

```
peopleDF = spark.read.json(json_input, schema=testschema, multiLine=True)

peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

teenagerNamesDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
display(teenagerNamesDF)
```

Given the JSON file, i expect a null value for e_1 due to the type mismatch (e.g. checking for integer but given string). However, this also causes all other values to be null also.

result:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

However, when I move this nested 'e' block down in the structure, it appears that is able to populate the fields before the block where the type mismatch occurs. E.g.

```
{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c",
    "d": "d",
    "e": {
        "e_1": "2"
    }

}
```

result:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

It seems that type mismatching in nested JSON structures stop/halts schema validation. How can this be solved?

Comment: the first JSON is not valid, it has a comma after the "d" and also you are missing the comma after "e" object.   try https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Oh thanks for mentioning it. Made a mistake while anonymizing the object :)

Comment: no problem.  with the fixed JSON, does your code read it correctly?

Comment: No, it does not complain about the structure of the JSON object.

Comment: ah, that's right. I could be wrong but I am vaguely remember this is due to how Pyspark3 parsing the object from start to end and it exits parsing when it finds the first error. if you force reading only the valid part `df.select('a', 'b', 'c', 'd').show()`, you should see the correct data even with the first JSON.  I don't have a good reference handy but you could search about `_corrupt_record`.